# React: prevent showing application before redirecting to Keycloak IDP page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, keycloak

I am developing a React application and using Keycloak for authentication and authorization for the entire app. There won't be any unsecured routes. Therefore, I am initializing KeyCloak in my index.js file.
I also skip KeyCloak's vanilla login page since all logins will be done using MS IDP.
Only the KeyCloak adapter is being used and can be used, no other third party package.

It works just fine, but any route accessed flashes for a split second before the redirection can happen.

I have KeyCloak as a service like this:

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

const _kc = new (Keycloak as any)("/keycloak.json");

const initKeycloak = (reactRender: any, component: any, domMethod: any) => {
  _kc
    .init({})
    .then(() => {
      _kc.login({ idpHint: "azureAD" });
    })
    .then(() => {
      reactRender(component, domMethod("root"));
    });
};
```

And my index.js file looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";
import keycloakService from "./keyCloakService";

const q = document.getElementById.bind(document);

keycloakService.initKeycloak(ReactDOM.render, <App />, q);
```

Since checking for authentication is async I thought I could pass the ReactDOM.render method and call it succesfully only when authentication has happened.
However, even with this approach, I cannot get it to work and the routes are being flashed for a split second.

How can I achieve this without using any third party packages?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change the behavior and display the App component only if the auth variable is true returned from the KeyCloak service.

Comment: How does this impact users who enter incorrect or unauthorized credentials? Does it prevent you from being able to provide unsecured routes altogether?